# How can I get the function's type from a call expression?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to make unit test to check (and to learn how function resolving works), for function overloading that take lvalue instead of const lvalue reference for primitive types in some math functions, that the good function is being called. I did not found any usual pattern about it.

```
struct A {/* ... */};

A f(A) {} // #1
A&& f(A&&) {} // #2
// Or some very complicated template overloading

int main() {
    f(A()); // call #2 ; How to get it ?
}

// I want to have:
// typeid(f).name();
```

Is it possible to get `typeid(f)` from `context` at compile-time ? (like gcc s complaining)

"Pseudo code" :

```
std::cout << typeid(f with args A()).name() << std::endl 
// >> "A&& f(A&&)"   (#2)
```

With only `typeid(f)`, the compiler (gcc 7.3.0 on Ubuntu x64)

```
/home/xyzz/project/tests/RunTests.cpp:22: erreur : overloaded function with no contextual type information
     typeid(tst).name();
            ^~~
```

With `typeid(f())`, it returns actually **the return** type

**Suggested answer:** `std::result_of`. The template parameters are not rebuild, but we can get the function type.

Comment: I believe that you have made a reasonable effort to compose your question. Unfortunately, nevertheless, I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: I edited more consisely because I think templates are not part of the question

Comment: So you want to, given some expression `f(args...)`, find out the fully qualified type of the `f` that is chosen by overload resolution? In string form. `decltype` or `result_of` will tell you what it returns - is that enough for you? Seeing as you already know the type of the arguments. I don't get why your example would say `void` though as none of your functions return `void`. Overall this is a pretty confusing question, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I think this is that.

Comment: Suggested title: _"How can I get the function's type from a call expression?"_

Comment: My comment was on another answer that has since been deleted. But if what your asking is "given args a,b,c.. and function f, how can I get a string representing which overload is being selected", I'm pretty sure you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work on my machine. How close is it to what you want?

```
    std::cout
      << typeid( static_cast<void (*)(A)>(f) ).name() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Seems fairly pointless to ask for the name of a type ... by giving it that type though. I think the idea is that the OP doesn't know what the type is (not directly at the callsite, at least). This is like saying "here's how to have the compiler tell you what the type of an `int` is"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, yes. I assume that the apparent pointlessness is the result of OP's reduction of what would otherwise have been a complex example to MCVE. But maybe I have misunderstood the question. Undoubtedly, OP will clarify soon!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, on second thought, you are right. The only thing my answer does is tell you whether the type is known to the compiler. Hm.